# Moto G won't go th Home Screen when unlocked

Tags: motorola-moto-g

When I unlock my Moto G, instead of going to the Home Screen, it goes to my Contacts page. I can't see where to change it so that it opens on my home screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're swiping from the bottom left across.  Swipe up from the bottom middle and it will got to the hone page.  This was driving me nuts too.